# Symbology sample box in QGIS is not showing required symbol?

Tags: qgis, symbology

The sample box that is used in the legend doesn't look like the actual map when I use point pattern fill in QGIS. The box is mostly empty with a partial point showing in the corner.

I have tried different distances/displacements but none of them move the point in the sample box.

[image: Styling error]

Comment: I usually just redo the pattern in an additional box and overlay it over the legend symbol.

Answer (score 1):

This can happen with a few different things, for me it's usually hatched line fills.

I found the only way to combat it is to offset the symbols/lines by trial and error until the legend looks right. If that starts messing with your canvas symbology then create a duplicate layer just for use in the legend and only offset the symbology for that one.